# Divisibility properties of Chow groups (beyond Roitman's theorem)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups

For affine varieties over separably closed fields, there are classical vanishing theorems for cohomology. For an affine variety $X$ of dimension $d$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we have ${\rm H}^i_{\rm sing}(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Z})=0$ for $i>d$ by Andreotti-Fraenkel; and the corresponding vanishing for étale cohomology of affine varieties is the Artin vanishing theorem.

Now we can use cycle class maps to compare Chow groups to singular or étale cohomology. For an affine variety $X$ of dimension $d$ over an algebraically closed field, the cycle class map ${\rm CH}^i(X)\to{\rm H}^{2i}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ will then map to zero for all $i>\lfloor d/2\rfloor$. On the other hand, one of the consequences of Roitman's theorem is that in the above situation, the Chow group of zero-cycles ${\rm CH}^d(X)$ is uniquely divisible (discussed e.g. in a paper of Srinivas on torsion $0$-cycles on affine varieties). So, for the zero-cycles, the cycle class map is then at least an isomorphism modulo primes.

In particular, we can think of the unique divisibility of the top Chow group (for affine varieties over algebraically closed fields) as an analogue of the classical cohomological vanishing theorems above. For some reason, I am wondering if it might generally be the case that the Chow groups of an affine (smooth if necessary) $d$-dimensional variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field might be uniquely divisible in degrees $i>\lfloor d/2\rfloor$.

> Have these divisibility properties for the Chow groups below the top one been considered in the literature? Have conjectures been formulated somewhere? Are such divisibility properties compatible with other conjectures on the structure of Chow groups? Are such divisibility properties at least plausible, or are there some immediate counterexamples?

Part of my motivation comes from thinking that motivic cohomology and K-theory with torsion coefficients behave very "topological" (compare Bloch-Kato conjectures or the comparison of algebraic and étale K-theory). Also, for a smooth quasi-projective variety $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, we can consider the smooth affine variety obtained by the Jouanolou trick, i.e., pulling back the vector bundle torsor ${\rm GL}_{n+1}/\mathbb{G}_{\rm m}\times{\rm GL}_n\to\mathbb{P}^n$ to $X$. In this case, the relative dimension of the vector bundle torsor is $n$, and therefore we obtain a smooth affine variety where the Chow groups actually vanish, at least in the required range. Since it's also easy to construct affine varieties whose Chow groups of zero cycles are huge, a vanishing statement can't be true, but maybe a statement about unique divisibility could hold?

Finally, the unique divisibility would actually have strong consequences for vanishing of obstruction groups  and subsequently for actual splitting  statements in the classification of projective modules (which is mainly the motivation for asking this question).

Comment: Would you mind, please, specifying precisely what you mean by "uniquely divisible"?  For a smooth, projective curve $X$ of dimension $d=1$ and genus $g\geq 1$, the integer $i=1$ satisfies $i>\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$.  Yet the Chow group $\text{CH}^1(X)=\text{Pic}_{X/\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$ contains a subgroup $\text{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$ whose torsion is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{2g}.$  In what sense is this "uniqely divisible"?  I do completely agree that this subgroup is divisible, and that is enough to get injectivity of the cycle class map modulo primes.

Comment: @JasonStarr: my question is only about affine varieties, but you make a good point. I should probably specify that I would like to assume $\dim X\geq 2$ which is what I had in mind.

Comment: You are correct: I missed the affine hypothesis.  Thanks for stating the hypothesis again.  For a smooth, projective curve $X$, for a point $x\in X(\mathbb{C})$, the affine curve $X\setminus\{x\}$ also has $\text{CH}^1$ equal to $\text{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C})$.  There might be similar examples in higher dimension by taking a product of affine curves.

Comment: There exists smooth rational varieties $X$ of dimension $d$ over an algebraically closed field with $CH^i(X)\neq 0$, but $N$ torsion for all $i<d$ for a fixed $N$.

Comment: @Mohan: thanks, that sounds very interesting. Where can I find the construction of such varieties? (If this settles the question and shows that my hopes were far too naive, you could also make this an answer.)

Comment: You can read my construction in my paper `Stably Free Modules' in Am. J. Math. 1983. Also, in my comment above, I should have (clearly) said $0<i$.

Comment: @Mohan: ah, I knew about the paper. Fantastic construction! Unfortunately I didn't realize that clearing the denominators in the intermediate variety $X_n$ provides a counterexample to my question. Thank you very much, this was very helpful. If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.